# Count of random numbers from a string java

Tags: java, string, count

This is a homework problem with a rule that we cant use arrays.
I have to make a program that will generate ten random numbers , append it to a string with a comma after each number. 

I then have to give a count of each random number and remove the highest frequency number from the string.

 The only issue i cannot solve is how to give a count of each number.
Lets say the string is  "1,1,2,4,5,6,6,2,1,1" or "1124566211" with the commas removed.

How can I go about an output something like

```
1 = 4
2 = 2
4 = 1
5 = 1
6 = 2
Removing all numbers of max frequency
245662
```

Where the left side is the number and the right is the count.

EDIT: Range is 1 between 10, exclusing 10. It is testing the frequency of each digit i.e. how many times does 1 appear, how many times does 2 appear etc. Also its due tonight and my prof doesnt answer that fast :/

Comment: Can't use arrays? I don't see the point. What do they teach in schools these days?

Comment: I suppose if you can't use an array `HashMap` is out of the question...

Comment: More seriously though, are you counting the *digit* frequency, or the frequency of each number? Is there a range for the random numbers?

Comment: Your teacher is paid to help you. If you do not know where to begin, you should ask them. They will be able to give you a level of help which they feel is appropriate, without undermining the whole point of the exercise. If they feel you should be able to solve it based on what you have covered so far, they will then know that you are struggling and will do their best to catch you up. If we just do it for you, you won't learn anything. Even if we just "start you off", it is possible that you will miss then teacher's intended learning goals, making the whole thing kind of pointless.

Comment: @user2023608 No, it isn't the same thing. Parsing the numbers isn't a problem. Counting their frequency without an array is just dumb.

Comment: @erickson Stack Overflow is the unofficial home of bad problems set by teachers with unnecessary constraints. Real life is irrelevant, now write me a program without using any vowels.

Comment: @erickson/@Michael I'm laughing so hard right now...

Comment: @Michael I thought that was what Code Golf was for, not SO!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HashMap. A string representation of the num will be used as the key and you will have an Integer value representing the frequency it occurs.

Loop through the string of nums and put them to the HashMap, if the num already exists in the map, update the value to be the (current value + 1).

Then you can iterate through this map and keep track of the current max, at the end of this process you can find out which nums appear most frequently.

**Note**: HashMap uses Arrays under the covers, so clarify with your teacher if this is acceptable...

Comment: I like it. Can't use an array huh? Okay, here's a `HashMap`!

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty string and append as you go, check frequency with regex. IDK what else to tell you. But yeah, considering that a string is pretty much just an array of characters it's kinda dumb.

Answer (score 0):

You can first say that the most common integer is 0, then compare it with the others one by one, replacing the oldest one with the newest one if it written more times, finally you just rewritte the string without the most written number.

Not the most efficient and clean method, but it works as an example!

```
    String Text = "1124566211"; // Here you define the string to check

    int maxNumber = 0;
    int maxNumberQuantity = 0; // You define the counters for the digit and the amount of times repeated


    //You define the loop and check for every integer from 0 to 9
    int textLength = Text.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {


        int localQuantity = 0; //You define the amount of times the current digit is written
        for(int ii = 0; ii < textLength; ii ++) {

            if(Text.substring(ii, ii+1).equals(String.valueOf(i)))
                localQuantity ++;

        }


        //If it is bigger than the previous one you replace it
        //Note that if there are two or more digits with the same amount it will just take the smallest one
        if(localQuantity > maxNumberQuantity) {
            maxNumber = i;
            maxNumberQuantity = localQuantity;
        }
    }


    //Then you create the new text without the most written character
    String NewText = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < textLength; i ++) {

        if(!Text.substring(i,i+1).equals(String.valueOf(maxNumber))) {
            NewText += Text.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    //You print it
    System.out.println(NewText);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help to give you a count for each char. I typed it quickly off the top of my head, but hopefully it at least conveys the concept. Keep in mind that, at this point, it is loosely typed and definately not OO. In fact, it is little more than pseudo. This was done intentionally. As you convert to proper Java, I am hoping that you will be able to get a grasp of what is happening. Otherwise, there is no point in the assignment.

```
function findFrequencyOfChars(str){

    for (i=0; i<str; i++){

        // Start by looping through each char. On each pass a different char is 
        // assigned to lettetA

        letterA = str.charAt(i);
        freq = -1;
        for (j=0; j<str; j++){

            // For each iteration of outer loop, this loops through each char, 
            // assigns it to letterB, and compares it to current value of 
            // letterA.

            letterB = str.charAt(j);
            if(letterA === letterB){
                freq++
            }
        }
        System.Out.PrintLn("the letter " + letterA + " occurs " + freq +" times in your string.")  
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that freq is initialized at -1. This is to offset the fact that each letter will always be equal to itself.